# Logging filename and lines

Tags: python-3.x, xml, logging

I've got a script parsing different xmls, each of them has different records.
I want to log the NameErrors (or others type of errors) with the name of the xml and the line in which it occurs.

I'm using logging and I've made this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import csv
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='errors.log', filemode='w' ,level=logging.DEBUG)

with open(input_file, "r") as file:
     content = file.read()
     soup_all = bs4(content, "xml")
     for soup in soup_all.find_all("record"):
        if soup.find("srw:extrarecorddata") is not None:
            extraRecordData = soup.find("srw:extrarecorddata")
        elif soup.find("srw:extraRecordData") is not None:
            extraRecordData = soup.find("srw:extraRecordData")
        uri = extraRecordData.find("uri").get_text()
        types = extraRecordData.find("typedoc").get_text()
        logging.debug("something raised an exception:", exc_info=True)
```

This just write on the file "DEBUG:root:something raised an exception: NoneType: None". I think I need to use the formatter (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects), but I don't understand how.

Comment: Hi Lara, the `[loop to get metadata]` is kind of the important part as if you want to catch exceptions you will need to use [`try - except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) catch the exceptions and add them to your logger along with other data.

Comment: I've updated that part, thanks

Comment: And when are you getting the exceptions? can you also attach those so we can understand. It isn't very obvious what you are trying to do. logger formatting is just that, a format, it does not add data you didn't put in the logger. For that you will have to catch `Exceptions` and write them to your logger. lxml doesn't support line numbers, [as stated in bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#line-numbers). The name of the xml you already have in `input_file` and you can add that to the log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create format at first and setFormatter for your logger like below.

```
formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(filename='errors.log', filemode='w' ,level=logging.DEBUG, format=formater )
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')

...your code
logging.debug('some thing wrong', exc_info=True)

# output will like this
# 2020-05-21 22:49:49,612 - logger - DEBUG - some thing wrong
```

https://realpython.com/python-logging/

This is a good article let you learn more about logging in python.